# VBA Rename File saving wrong Filetype

Tags: excel, vba

This script should go into a folder full of excel files, rename the files by the author name & a count, and save them to a new folder.

However, this now saves the file not as an excel document, but the filetype is also the name of the author and the count.

I have edited the code from the suggested comments but now I receive this error:

[Runtime Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKtOX.png)

Did I edit the code wrong?

```
    Sub RenameExcelFilesbyAuthor()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim Counter As Integer

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
.Title = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Excel Folder"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
 If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
 
 'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xlsx*"
 
 'Target Path with Ending Extention
 myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
 
 Counter = 1
 
 'Loop through each Excel file in folder
 Do While myFile <> ""
  'ReadOnly = False
    Set wb = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        wb.Close
    Else
    Counter = Counter + 1
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
     DoEvents

   'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
   ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author") = Author
     wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\max\Documents\New folder\" & wb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author") & Counter & myExtension, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
   
   'Save and Close Workbook
     wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
     
   'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
     DoEvents
    End If
   
   'Get next file name
     myFile = Dir
     
 Loop
 
 'Message Box when tasks are completed
 MsgBox "Task Complete!"
 
ResetSettings:
 'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVPT1.png
```

Comment: Change `xlWorkbookNormal` to `xlWorkbookDefault` and concatenate the extension `.xlsx` to your filename.

Comment: You're missing the file extension when saving the file.

Comment: I edited the code to reflect both of your changes, which I really appreciate, but now I get an error. The original post has been edited to show the image. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should `Debug.Print` that filename and inspect it yourself... make sure it's not too long, doesn't have typos, doesn't have illegal characters, etc.

Comment: Every time I put debug.print before the filename I get an error saying I cant put it there. Where would I put debug print?